# ¿Cómo crear un valor por default cuando no exista parametro o valor preciso en la URL?

Tags: php

Mediante el siguiente código:

```
$current_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_link = explode('publishers=', $current_link);
$publishers = array_pop($current_link);

echo $publishers;
```

Puedo encontrar en la URL un parámetro preciso y, obtener su valor, es decir que si en la URL esta conformada de la siguiente manera:

```
http://example.com/demo.php?e=1&?a=2&?/publishers=11DATg
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado `11DATg` pero cuando no existe este parámetro: `publishers` me imprime la URL completa:

```
http://example.com/demo.php?e=1&?a=2&?/publish1=11DATg
```

Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo darle un valor por defaul cuando no exista este parámetro: `publishers` para que en vez de imprimir la URL completa me imprima este valor por defaul `Orgánico`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tenés que hacer es chequear si existe la key `1` en `$current_link` cuando hacés el `explode`. Si existe, guardás lo que haya, sino guardás `Orgánico`.
El problema con usar `array_pop()` es que extrae el último ítem, pero en el caso que haya uno solo, extra el *primero*.

```php
$current_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_link = explode('publishers=', $current_link);
$publishers = $current_link[1] ?? 'Orgánico';

echo $publishers;
```

Usando [??](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) chequeamos si `isset($current_link[1])`, si es true, entonces guardamos su valor, sino, guardamos `Orgánico`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por el tiempo dedicado, saludos y feliz navidad :)

Comment: @Mary si los parámetros siempre los estás recibiendo por `GET` y no es que tenés directamente un string que es una URL, tené en cuenta lo que dice @LuisAcxis. Es mejor que usar `explode()`.

Comment: No funciona lo que comento @LuisAcxis, si la URL está como los ejemplos proporcionado está muestra el mensaje de que no existe y, por lo tanto me daría como respuesta `Orgánica` dado el código fue planteado por una pregunta para obtener el dicho valor cuando está coincida por parámetro específico en la URL.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto seria que hicieras una validación de esta manera con cada parámetro que estas enviando.

```php
if (isset($_GET["publishers"])) {
    // Existe la variable publishers
   $publishers = $_GET["publishers"];
} else {
    // No existe la variable publishers
}
```