# ¿Cómo descartar valores fuera de un parámetro específico?

Tags: php

En algunas plataformas y, redes sociales abre el sitio web pero incluye otros parámetros en la URL de mi sitio web como referencia al ser redireccionados por ejemplo:

```
http://example.com/demo.php?publishers=11DATg?NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN
```

Ahora sin importar como este conformada la URL, ya sea de esta manera:

```
http://example.com/demo.php?e=1&?a=2&?/publishers=11DATg?NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN&?d=wokfdk
```

Cómo obtener el valor de un parámetro específico descartando otros que terminen en: `/ . ? &`

Dado que el siguiente código:

```php
$current_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_link = explode('publishers=', $current_link);
$publishers = $current_link[1] ?? 'Orgánico';

echo $publishers;
```

Me imprime otros datos no deseados, datos impresos:

```
11DATg?NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN

#Segunda impresión
11DATg?NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN&?d=wokfdk
```

Lo que solo deseo obtener:

```
11DATg
```

Al momento de querer realizar la estadística y, recompensación se complica dado que la consulta se realiza dado el ID de referencia que es `11DATg`

Aclaró que no utilizó la siguiente función `if (isset($_GET["publishers"]))` dado que a mí código imprime el valor que coincida con dicho parámetro sin importar si está, está mal escrita o mal conformada la URL, lo que no sucede con `if (isset($_GET["publishers"]))`

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos cuál es el problema? Tal y como has planteado la pregunta no logro determinar qué problema tienes exactamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, edité mi pregunta. En resumen mi código PHP imprime datos demás, no deseado es decir lo siguiente: `11DATg?NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN
y
11DATg?NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN&?d=wokfdk` por lo tanto quiero descargar otros datos cuando en el parámetro específico `publishers=valor` terminé en ` / . ? &` creo que son los datos más comunes que puede existir en la URL, en conclusión obtener solo este valor `11DATg` y no otros no deseado tal como lo hice en la edición :) ese es el problema amigo :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al utilizar:

```php
explode('publishers=', $current_link);
```

siempre obtendrás un array con 2 valores. El HTTP_HOST y sus parámetros por la izquierda y lo que sigue a `publishers=` por la derecha. Por tanto, tu resultado siempre será el mismo.

Tendrías que extraer la subcadena de tu resultado para obtener lo que necesitas:

```php
$publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '?'));

echo $publishers;
```

Si tienes más caracteres que verificar aparte de '?', deberías usar condicionales:

```php
if ($current_link[1]) {
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '?')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '?'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '&')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '&'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '/')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '/'));
    }
} else {
    $publishers = 'Orgánico';
}
```

Comment: Hola, funciona pero quedó sin efecto el uso de esta acción `#$publishers = $current_link[1] ?? 'Orgánico';` que era que imprimía un valor por `default` cuando no existía este parámetro `publishers` en la la URL :(

Comment: Y fue una pregunta que abrí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318300/cómo-crear-un-valor-por-default-cuando-no-exista-parametro-o-valor-preciso-en-l para obtener ese valor por default cuando no exista dicho parámetro :(

Comment: Si deseas mantenerlo usa: ```` $publishers = (substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '?'))) ?? 'Orgánico'; ````

Comment: Muestra este error amigo `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` por otra parte se puede agregar más reglas aparte de `?` porque sucede cuando va así en la URL `publishers=11DATg&?osfklskdk288` me imprime así: `11DATg&`

Comment: Dependiendo de la variedad de valores que se puedan encontrar en la url, tendrías que usar condicionales con los caracteres que aparezcan primero. Editaré mi respuesta agregando esos casos.